# Data validation in ContentProvider not working

Tags: android, validation, insert, android-contentprovider

I try to prevent users from passing in empty input.

```
 private Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {

    if (contentValues.getAsString(StudentEntry.COLUMN_NAME) == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A name is required");
    }

    if (contentValues.getAsString(StudentEntry.COLUMN_CITY) == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A city is required");
    }
    //Perform insert operation here.
}
```

Invalid data is still able to go into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following validation:

```
if(!contentValues.containsKey(StudentEntry.COLUMN_NAME) || TextUtils.isEmpty(contentValues.getAsString(StudentEntry.COLUMN_NAME))) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("A name is required");
}
```